# Convert Word to excel for certain text based on fixed pattern

Tags: excel, ms-word

Word screenshot:
[image]
Excel screenshot
[image]

I have a requirement to convert from word to excel format.

I have multiple issues in word format. for each issue there is cause and resolution (overall) & cause and resolution for parts of the issue (part is indicated in brackets). The text section has to be extracted and added in the destination excel format.

Attached is the source file in docx and the expected excel format.

Any solution or direction towards a solution would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sri

Not tried. Need a solution or direction